# Getting result from SQL with min, max and condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn some (advance or more complex) SQL.
Let's say I have a table of cars, with information of every car.
Then I have another table with cars being sold, some are new, and some are used.

I want the user to be able to look up a car, a Honda civic 2016 for instance, and see the car info.
But also want the user to see *all* Honda civic 2016 cars being sold, including the highest and lowest price for that particular year/model, organized by new and used.

What would be the most efficient way to retrieve all the information - the car info and the ones being sold to display on a page!

These are my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    last VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    phone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    joined DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE Cars(
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    year INT(4) NOT NULL,
    trim VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Market(
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    car_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    condition VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    notes VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),

    CONSTRAINT cfk FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES cars(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT ufk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

It looks redundant to me and doomed to get slow as the tables get bigger. So I would appreciate if somebody shows me a better way.

```
/* Get car information*/
SELECT *
FROM Cars 
WHERE make = 'Honda' 
  AND model = 'Civic' 
  AND year = '2017'   
  AND trim = 'EX'; 

/* I also would like to get the min and max price for this particular car*/
/* ?? How ?? */

/* Get (new) cars being sold and sellers */
SELECT M.*, U.* 
FROM Market M 
INNER JOIN Users ON M.user_id = U.id 
WHERE make = 'Honda' 
  AND model = 'Civic' 
  AND year = '2017' 
  AND color = 'white' 
  AND trim = 'EX' 
  AND condition = 'NEW';

/* Get (used) cars being sold and sellers */
SELECT M.*, U.* 
FROM Market M 
INNER JOIN Users ON M.user_id = U.id 
WHERE make = 'Honda' 
  AND model = 'Civic' 
  AND year = '2017' 
  AND color = 'white' 
  AND trim = 'EX' 
  AND condition = 'USED';
```

I ultimately would like to get something like the following using PHP:

```
{
    car: {
        make: "Honda",
        model: "Civic",
        year: 2017,
        trim: "EX"
    },
    market: {
        new: {
            min: 'overall min',
            max: 'overall max',
            data: [{
                seller:{
                    name: "John",
                    last: "Smith",
                    phone: "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                    email: "email@domain.com",
                },
                car: {
                    price: 15000,
                    color: "white",
                    condition: "used",
                    notes: "Some notes about the car"
                }
            }]
        },
        used: { 
            min: 'overall min',
            max: 'overall max',
            data: [{
                seller:{
                    name: "John",
                    last: "Smith",
                    phone: "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                    email: "email@domain.com",
                },
                car: {
                    price: 15000,
                    color: "white",
                    condition: "new",
                    notes: "Some notes about the car"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to put into that format once I retrieve the information. Also I would have to paginate through the database.

Basically I am interested on knowing the best way to do what Amazon does. An item is for sale from different vendors, and at different prices. Amazon provides information about the item being sold; its condition, price, seller, etc. Also, Amazon gives you the lowest, highest price and the information about the item in general. What is the best approach?

Comment: I think you forgot the column `price` in your `CREATE TABLE Market ...`, figured out what you meant.  Data type `DECIMAL (10,2)` is probably sane for `price`.

Comment: `color` is missing also..

Comment: I appreciate those remarks however, the focus of attention is the performance and the best way to accomplish that. I am able to manage the rest!

Comment: Fantastic Super pleased you found the answer you were looking for! You have provided an excellent learning opportunity.The comments are not for you so much as for others that will visit the site later to benefit from your question and the answers provided. The purpose of the corrections is to minimize confusion and keep future visitors from re-inventing the debugging wheel, so to speak, when they try to work out the examples. Nothing personal here! We are all just trying to help each other out. StackOverflow is a wonderful resource -- and you are a large part of that:) Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 6):

Four queries should be fine:

- One query to get the general info about the type of Car
- Another query to get the min/max prices by condition
- Then queries each to get the Market list of available cars for new and used.  You could do these two queries lazily - first display to your shoppers the basic car info and min/max new/used prices, and then when your shopper clicks on the used number (like Amazon), fetch the Market offers just for the used cars.

For the min/max sales, you are needing to do an **aggregation**, so `GROUP BY` is your friend.  Try this:

```
SELECT `condition`, MIN(price) min_price, MAX(price) max_price
FROM Cars
JOIN Market ON (Cars.id = Market.car_id)
WHERE make = 'Honda'
  AND model = 'Civic'
  AND year = '2017'
  AND trim = 'EX'
GROUP BY `condition`;
```

Your other queries look good. As the tables grow and you want to keep the queries quick, **indexing** will help. Basic rule is that the fields that are part of your `WHERE` predicate are good to have indexed.  Also any `JOIN` keys between tables are usually good to have indexed.  Try an index on `Cars(make, model, year, trim)`.

Also, `condition` is a reserved word in MySQL 5.7, which is why I escaped using backticks.  Consider using `cond` instead, and if you only have a few conditions {"new", "used"}, consider using an `ENUM` data type.  Beware `MIN` and `MAX` are also reserved db words.

Comment: Just a typo in your query: `MIN(price) max_price` should be `MIN(price) min_price`...

Comment: @EmileEichenberger Good eye. Fixed typo.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help! What about when the tables get really big? Should I then think about indexing?

Comment: To get the best performance out of the given query you should define composite indexes: `Cars(make, model, year, trim)` and `Market(car_id, condition, price)`. The order of the columns in the first index isn't important for this query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the order for the Cars index matters if you allow users to specify partial criteria.  Suppose I want to look for Honda Civic, years 2010-2017, with any trim.  If it was indexed on `Cars(trim, make, model, year)`, then you would get a full table scan.  Best to lead (prefix) your index with the most likely columns that will be used. If not possible to boil down to one index for all common uses, multiple composite indexes can help.

Comment: @JoshuaHuber This is correct. But I wrote: "... isn't important **for this query**". So the order can be changed to fit other queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the information you need with two queries.
For example - You can get the lowest price for new and used cars along with the car info in one query using correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT c.*, 
    (SELECT MIN(m.price) FROM Market m WHERE m.car_id = c.id and m.condition = 'NEW')  as new_min_price,
    (SELECT MIN(m.price) FROM Market m WHERE m.car_id = c.id and m.condition = 'USED') as used_min_price
FROM Cars c
WHERE c.make = 'Honda' 
  AND c.model = 'Civic' 
  AND c.year = '2017'   
  AND c.trim = 'EX'
```

For best performance I would create composite indexes `Cars(make, model, year, trim)` and `Market(car_id, condition, price)`.
The order of the columns in the first index isn't important and you can change it.
The optimizer can adjust the execution plan to the order you define.
However the order for the second index must be this way to get the lowest price most efficiently.
If you have an index on `Market(car_id)` (which is probably created by the FOREIGN KEY definition), you can drop it.
The new composite index can be used instead.

Note that I didn't include the highest price, since I don't think anybody cares.
But you can get it the same way as you get the lowest price by useing `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`.

There is another way to get the same data using "conditional aggregation":

```
SELECT c.*,
    MIN(CASE m.condition = 'NEW' THEN m.price END)  as new_min_price,
    MIN(CASE m.condition = 'USED' THEN m.price END) as used_min_price
FROM Cars c
JOIN Market m ON m.car_id = c.id
WHERE c.make = 'Honda' 
  AND c.model = 'Civic' 
  AND c.year = '2017'   
  AND c.trim = 'EX'
GROUP BY c.id
```

But this query can't use the indexes in the best way, since the engine will need to loop through all offers in order to find the lowest price.

Now to get all the offers from the `Market` table, you don't need to execute two queries (one for each condition).
You can fetch them all with one query and group the result by the `condition` field in your application language.
Also since you already know the `car_id` from the first query, you can use it as the search criteria, so you don't need to touch the `cars` table again.
(Note that your last two queries wouldn't work without a JOIN with the `cars` table, since the market table doesn't have the columns `make`, `model`, `year` and `trim`.)

```
SELECT
    m.condition
    m.id as market_id,
    m.user_id,
    u.name,
    u.last
FROM Market m
INNER JOIN Users u ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE m.car_id = ?
ORDER BY price
```

Note that if you use `SELECT m*, u*`, the `id` field will be ambiguous since it is defined in both tables.
So you should list all fields you want to fetch and use an alias for ambiguous columns like `m.id as market_id`.

You didn't mention the language you use - So I can't tell you exactly how to group the result by the `condition` field.
For example with PHP PDO you could use the `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` mode.
However if your language doesn't support such functionality you can group/split the result in a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people may not like this but I have solved some of the most complex SQL statements using MS Access. First simply use MS access to design tables and relationships. Then use the query builder to design queries. Then change query builder to SQL view to view the SQL Statements. To use this SQL code on other DB engines require minor changes.

SQL Coding Kings hate MS Access but in reality, it is the best development tool when starting to build any database. It allows easy and fast changes, and in single user mode is the fastest DB around.

If you plan to build lots of databases and want to save time by not becoming a SQL coding king then us MS Access as a development tool!